# iPhone 7 — Antenna stripes change their color

Tags: iphone

I've bought my iPhone 7 September 16th and noticed today a change in color of the antenna stripes - they are getting blueish:

[image]

I always wear it in my jeans pocket without any case or sleeve. 
Is there something I can do to clean the stripes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a very white and very soft eraser (Staedtler Mars Plastic) did the job: there are almost no indigo stains on antenna stripes and no scratches on the phone at all after gently erasing for few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it on an iPhone, but I'd bet [melamine foam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melamine_foam) would work.

Comment: But you know what melamine foam is an abrasive like sandpaper?

Comment: Yep, that's how it works.

Comment: "Don't use window cleaners, household cleaners, compressed air, aerosol sprays, solvents, ammonia, or **abrasives** to clean your iPhone." https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht207123